# Paypal chained payments( shipping address)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a question about shipping address on paypal chained payments 
So on my app(buyer-receiver1(me where I collect my %)receiver2(seller where I pass the rest of the money).The flow is like this:Set actionType: CREATE, call PAY API, receive payKey,setPaymentOption(where I set the shipping address),redirect to paypal page to pay(on review page I can see shipping address)
After ogin in seller page and I have this message: Seller Protection Not Eligible(We have no shipping address on file.)
So I emailed paypal stuff and this was their response:

As stated in the documentation of Adaptive payment(chained payment). The sender does not know the existence of secondary and vice versa, hence the secondary receiver won't be able to see who the buyer is. If you would like this to be possible, the only way is via IPN. whereby the IPN must include the secondary receiver.

So my question is: is there something I can do beside IPN where I can transmit the shipping address to the seller for seller protection? If not can you point me some tutorials beside documention. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the seller the primary receiver and yourself the secondary receiver?  You don't actually need the shipping address, so if you're the secondary receiver then it doesn't matter if you don't get it.

Comment: This works but I don't want the buyer to see the store email address and vice-versa + that they can see my % fee